# Why Potts model has a first order phase transition when the state number is large enough?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition

I have known the fact that Potts model has first-order phase transition in 2D when the number of states $q>4$. And similar behavior happens in 3D and 4D etc. I also know that there is some proof of the fact, both from physicist
like Rodney Baxter or mathematican like Hugo Duminil-Copin. However it is not easy for me to draw some understand from these highly-technical arguments.

Are there some simple explanations for the fact?

Comment: To show that this happens for all $q>4$ is hard, but it is not so difficult to show that this happens for very large values of $q$. Probably the simplest rigorous approach is the one described [here](http://www.ihes.fr/~duminil/publi/2016Newprooflargeq.pdf). There are several alternative (older) approaches, but they are more difficult (some of which also apply in higher dimensions). A nice one deduces this from the observation that this is true for the mean-field Potts model, see [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~lchayes/lchayes_website_folder/old_publications_folder/bc_mft.pdf).

Comment: Also, note that there may well be no particularly intuitive way to understand why behavior changes at $q=4$, since this is not true for interactions of sufficiently long (but finite) range. In that case, the transition is of first order for any $q\geq 3$, just as in higher dimensions.